# find the radius of a circle given the length of some lines

Tags: geometry

Can anyone help me on this? Thank you very much!

How many units are in the length of the radius of the circle which passes through points X, Y, and Z? Express your answer as a decimal rounded to the nearest tenth.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** your points can be considered $(-8,0)$, $(0,6)$, and $(12,0)$.  A circle's center is the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors of segments between points on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$XZ$ is a chord of the circle. Thus, the radius must be on the perpendicular bisector.

Indeed, if $X = (-8, 0), Y = (0, 6)$ and $Z = (12, 0)$ then we know that $O = (2, a)$ for some $a$.

Now use the fact that the distance between the center and all the points are zero.